# How to isolate edits to an area in Blender 2.8?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

I'm trying to follow along with the good old Anvil tutorial and I'm running into a snag where I can't limit the scope of my proportional edit by hiding the areas I want to remain unaffected. Is there another means of doing this in Blender 2.8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Shortcuts are the same, unless you are using some non-default keymap.

<kbd>H</kbd> in Edit Mode hides the selected geometry.

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> in Edit Mode hides the un-selected geometry.

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> un-hides the hidden geometry.

Comment: Yeah, Hide still works, but even when a selection is hidden it is still being affected by a nearby proportional edit.

Edit* Nvm, I realized not all the applicable faces were being selected in my box select. Manually selecting each face solved my issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No biggie. Kindly flag the question as answered, if the answer solved your problem.